# How to determine the vertexes for a polygon whose outer edge is a given distance from a line or area in javascript on Google maps?

Tags: javascript, geocoding, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm

I have an exercise in problem solving for those who like that kind of thing. I'm working on a mapping application that uses Google Maps. A user first enters a series of coordinates and a "radius". The user then requests either a line or an area be plotted. The plots are taking place on Google Maps using polygons. In other words, given the blue line (or area) defined by the blue points and a distance, calculate the red points and draw the red polygon where the edges are of the given distance away from the user-provided edges:

[image: line]
 
[image: area]

I have managed to get this to work in "most" situations by calculate forward and reverse bearings, then finding the points with a bearing 90 degrees off these in the appropriate direction. For the arcs I just calculated the location points along that arc at 5 degree intervals. In the case of the inside of an acute angle, I determine where the two lines intersect and use that point, but this fails miserably sometimes when the cross-track distance at that point is greater than the radius that was provided.

I'm hoping someone knows of an easier way? Maybe one that works all the time regardless of the ratio of the cross-track to radius distances? Or maybe a library already exists to do this?

I hope what I'm trying to do makes sense... It's hard to put in words. Maybe if I had the words a search would have been helpful even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer turned out to be simpler than I thought. It took me back to a lesson I was taught during CompSci 101 almost 15 years ago:

"Use existing libraries whenever possible."

Once I found out (via googling), that what I'm looking for isn't called an "offset" or a "scale" but is actually called a "buffer" in GIS computing, it was simple. There are some great libraries like [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) by [Angus Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359538/angus-johnson) that can do it, but I wanted something JavaScript specific.

That brought me to [arcGIS](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/geometryservice.htm)'s GeometryService. They even have a [Google Maps version](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/gmaps/index.html) but it's only API v2. Luckily, there's an official, unsupported version I found via the arcGIS forums that works with GMaps API v3.

So, my solution was to use that, called [arcgislink](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/arcgislink/docs/reference.html), and it's buffer function works perfectly with Google Maps LatLng points, Google Maps Polygons/Polylines, and any of the standard arcGIS types. Anyone else needing to do this with Google Maps, I highly recommend looking at their libraries.

Comment: Hi, using your arcGIS method with complex polygons over a certain number of planes, the code requires some sort of proxxy. Did you run in to this prob and if so how did you solve it? CHeers

Comment: You are talking about Clipper and Javascript. Maybe this comes too late for your purposes, but just a little after your post the Javascript version of Clipper was released. Please see the demo: http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/5.0.2.1/main_demo.html. Clipper can do offsetting of polygons.

Answer (score 0):

In the general setting, this problem is quite difficult because it is a global one (you cannot just solve locally, at each polygon vertex but just handling the two incoming edges). And also uneasy because it involves circular arcs.

There is a solution which is quite unefficient but safe: assume you have a general polygon union algorithm (like http://gvu.gatech.edu/~jarek/graphics/papers/04PolygonBooleansMargalit.pdf); you will add inflated versions of every edge one by one (every time a rectangle and two half-disks approximated by polygons), together with the original polygon for closed shapes.

For the sake of efficiency, you can design a "sweepline" algorithm that works by slicing the plane with horizontal lines at every "event point", i.e. segment/arc endpoints and arc apexes, so that the configuration in every slice is simpler. Do you see what I mean ?

BTW, what do you call the "cross-track distance" ?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll check out your link when I get some time and see what I think. I'm not sure if there's a mathematical term for cross-track distance. I come from a navigation background. In navigation, the cross-track distance is the distance from a point on the surface of the earth to a great-circle line. So what I was saying is that if distance between one of the user-provided points and a line segment on the outer (aka calculated) shape is less than the distance provided to offset, the results can be very strange.